# make a memory dump of a large w3wp instance

Tags: iis, memory, dump

I have a web service that under normal conditions consume about 6-7 GB of memory. Sometimes, however, consumption spikes to 11-12 GB and I want to figure out why. For that I want to make a memory dump of the `w3wp.exe` running that service so I could analyze it in a debugger offline. I make dumps with a [procdump](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) by running

```
procdump.exe -ma w3wp.exe
```

it works fine for the normal case, but when the process uses 11 GB of memory the process gets terminated by some sort of IIS protection for non-responsive app pool and `procdump` terminates without creating any dump file. How do I work around that?

Comment: attach [VMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap) to the w3wp.exe and analyze the usage. for better way to analyze memory usage grow, use [WPR/WPA and analyze Referenceset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/wpa-reference-set)

Answer (score 1):

For dumping the memory of a process, you can try via the task manager with a right click on your process and Full memory Dump

Moreover, if it always fails, you can do a dump of all your RAM. For that, you can use **DumpIt**, I regulary use it and it never fails. But, the size of the dump will be the size of your RAM.

You will be able to work on it with volatility or other debugger

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The task manager way also fails. Will try the full memory dump.